# Laravel 5 - still use local path

Tags: php, laravel

I just uploaded my laravel to online server,
but i got this issue, it still use my local path this is when i go to index, all my other path also leads to MAMP, which cause errors:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [welcome] not found.

in FileViewFinder.php line 137
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/abc/resources/views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
at FileViewFinder->find('welcome') in Factory.php line 174
at Factory->make('welcome', array(), array()) in helpers.php line 856
at view('welcome') in web.php line 15
at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}() in Route.php line 176
at Route->runCallable() in Route.php line 147
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

how to fix this? thanks

Comment: did you hard core any values? did you updated the env file?

Comment: @jycr753 i don't see any string to that MAMP/htdocs

Comment: could you updated with the full error message?

Comment: @jycr753 i just update to full error message,

I just found the answer, this code

    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan config:clear

it helps fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer, so the laravel still use config cache that has the old path

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

It fix the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file, it worked.
The other solutions did not work for me.